# mailbox.item.body.getAsync returns an empty string when mail body contains invalid HTML

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

**Setup**
- Mac Outlook 2016 client

We have noticed that when we call [`mailbox.item.body.getAsync()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.3/Body#getasynccoerciontype-options-callback) method  (HTML coercion type) on a mail item with invalid HTML an empty string is returned:

```
<div> <div> Foo bar </div> </div>
```

The invalid HTML content refers to a scenario where there is no enclosing html tag.

The same call when performed in the web Outlook client (Chrome - Office 365) returns the body of the mail.

Comment: Thanks for raising it. Could you please share exact repro steps for us to help in debugging.

Comment: If the mail body contains  content like the snippet I have posted without proper starting and ending HTML tags (e.g. some div content without a html, head and body) the Mac Outlook API call returns an empty body.

Comment: We tried similar scenario using below code snippet 
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync('<div><div> Foo bar</div>', {coercionType: "html"}, function (setResult) {
      if (setResult.status == "succeeded")
       Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", function (getResult) { 
          if (getResult.status == "succeeded") console.log(getResult.value); 
       }); 
    });
But we are not able to report the issue. Can you check if this is the same scenario which you are referring to?

Comment: In our scenario we are not explicitly setting the content of the body but rather attempting to retrieve the body of a mail sent by another.

Comment: You will need to generate an email with invalid HTML without setting it.

Comment: Did you guys have any luck reproducing it with the step that I mentioned?